# Send SMS using cron job to a lot of users

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, sms

Helo,
I am having a problem sending around 40k users sms, I am using this

```
  $users = $this->game_model->get_all_subscribed_users();
  if(!empty($users))
  {
    foreach($users as $user)
    {
      $response = $this->_generate_question($user->id);
      $this->api_model->send_sms($user->mobile,$response,3);
    }
  }
```

The problem that I think the loop breaks at some point and it restart, people getting sms every 15 mins, even I set the sending only twice a day.
What could be the problem ? should I split the users to chunks, if so can someone help me out ?

Thanks

Comment: It is more question for your SMS gateway provider. Maybe something with quotas?

Comment: @Tpojka  I think i Have timeout on the server, but I can split the array and send chunks  but I cant figure how i can do it

Comment: For that you could [split array into chunks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Comment: @Tpojka Thanks, but could you help me more, like if I want to send only 1000 per time, how can I do it ? Thanks

Comment: Read that page I linked and see examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the code to make the loop break. I assume the problem you are having is the page actually timing out because this page would take quite a while to execute. To get around this you could run PHP via the Command Line Interface as there will be no timeout limit. In CodeIgniter you can run via CLI by using a similar set of commands

Navigate to your project directory `cd C:\xampp\project`

Run the required page `php index.php controller method`